# Error starting JSF application on Jboss 5.0

Tags: java, jsf, jboss5.x

I'm new to JSF, I've recently started working with a tutorial. I've created application exactly as the information provided in the tutorial. However when I start the server, I'm getting following error:

```
Exception sending context initialized event to listener instance of class org.jboss.web.jsf.integration.config.JBossJSFConfigureListener
java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration cannot be cast to com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration
    at com.sun.faces.config.WebConfiguration.getInstance(WebConfiguration.java:154)
    at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:145)
```

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" id="WebApp_ID" version="2.5">
    <display-name>Hello, World</display-name>
    <description>Welcome to JavaServerFaces</description>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/faces/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <listener>
        <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

</web-app>
```

As indicated in tutorial I've added jsf-api and jsf-impl in Web-Inf/lib, however googling for the same I found that jboss has its own jsf version which might be polluting my application with multiple jsf versions. If that's the case then how do I resolve the issue or if I'm wrong then what is the reason behind the error ?

Just to add, as I believe its the jar files conflit I've tried to add the jar files imported with jboss from `jboss-5.1.0.GA\server\default\deploy\jbossweb.sar\jsf-libs`, still all in vain.

Please help.

Comment: can you post the web.xml as well?

Comment: Initially I didn't had any listener in web.xml however as provided in the post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2558614/jsf-web-application-with-icefaces-compaonent I've added it trying to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A better way to cope up with the conflict is to add a context parameter in web.xml as I've mentioned below:

```
<context-param>
      <param-name>org.jboss.jbossfaces.WAR_BUNDLES_JSF_IMPL</param-name>
      <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Check out: [Bundling JSF Inside Your WAR](http://docs.jboss.org/jbossas/6/JSF_Guide/en-US/html/jsf.deployer.config.html)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how your Eclipse is configured(Java EE/JBoss tools and so on). But you should  add a server runtime to your webproject:

1. Add server runtime

1.1 open Server view in Eclipse

1.2 Context menu and then -> new Server->select JBoss 5.0 *server type*

1.3 Server runtime enviroment-> add

1.4 Home directory-> your sever home/default for example

1. Now change the buildpath of your webproject.

2.1. Add library->server runtime->select your new runtime

2.3 No JSF or other libs in your ear or in your webprojects Web-Inf/lib

Now you have all the Jboss-libs including the jsf-libs in your classpath - controlled by Eclipse - and you don't have to worry about setting jars from server lib and so on.

I hope it helps. In a similar way I just create a test-project

Comment: I don't understand what was wrong and how it worked but it did worked for me. Do you have any idea what was the issue ?
Thanks anyways :)

Comment: Hard to explain: You can put all the jars you use in your Web-Inf folder and for your project everything is allright for the moment. But be aware, that your project must work under a server environment. This server - the JBoss for example - interprets and deploys your app. There exist several class declarations, the interfaces of the jsf-specification and the concrete implementations and so on. You must treat with this fact during developing in your IDE. You do this by adding the several enviroment vars to your project. It's completely different from developing a standalone app. Hope it helps

Comment: The issue was same, so when you added the JBoss 5.0 runtime environment, you basically added the dependencies of JBoss and when you removed the local jars from your project as per point 2.3 you removed the conflict. That's how you got it working.

Comment: Firstly, when I added server I have already added jboss runtime environment, now I've tried both ways, by adding jar files explicity in build path and by adding them in WEB-INF/lib and it didn't worked. So with that when I added JBoss 5.0 runtime environment, Himanshu is right that it removed the conflict and worked for me, however I'm still not getting why it didn't worked earlier. Anyways thanks a lot @HimanshuBhardwaj and Jan Piel.

Comment: @JanPiel can you tell me what was the difference when I added server runtime environment while adding the server and adding the same runtime enviroment again in the build path ?

Comment: By adding the server environment to eclipse you declare the global server var in Eclipse. You can add several enviroments, for example a sec one for jboss 7.1 a third for Glassfish and so on. This enviroment holds the different jars from the default\lib and server\client and so on(expand the Runtime in  your projects classpath for seeing it). Now you've got two or more projects. Each cann have a reference to the same server environment. Understand the runtime enviroment like a big virtual jar, which can also be refenced by several projects.

Answer (score 0):

Yep looks like a jar version collision

Remove JSF dependencies from Application:
If you are building the project using maven,  you can set the dependencies scope to **provided**.

Remove dependencies scope from JSF (if you want to use your own jars.)
Consider using Jboss application description and exclude the JSF dependecies.

I am not aware of JBoss 5 XML format, so posting for JBoss 7

```
<jboss-deployment-structure>
    <deployment>
        <exclusions>
            <module name="com.sun.jsf-impl" />
        </exclusions>
    </deployment>
</jboss-deployment-structure>
```

Should be something similar to this.

Comment: I'm not using maven. Removing the jar files from web-inf it gives a ClassNotFoundException. Thanks for answering though !

Comment: Sorry, I'm not getting what does the other way mean here.

Comment: Trying to edit, the JBoss deployment descriptor for the application, in order to use jsf libraries, which are shipped with the webapp and not by Jboss itself, I have already attached a sample above. Sorry but I am not much aware of JBoss 5 so posted related to JBoss 7

Comment: I'm using eclipse and I don't know how do I edit its xml configuration as I'm unable to open it. And I couldn't find JBoss deployment descriptor in jboss folder either.

Comment: No, this file is project specific and has to be created, if required. And shipped as part of app. I am not aware of JBoss 5 structure so cannot comment much, how its supposed to be done for JBoss 5.

Comment: If we're talking about project specific deployment descriptor, then isn't its the web.xml only ?

Comment: No, thats the web application descriptor, JBoss deplyment description is basically the way your application is supposed to be deployed. But one thing just clicked, when you remove JSF libraries from your web-application you get ClassNotFoundException but it should have atleast picked the JSF libraries being shipped with JBoss which didn't happen.

Comment: Yeah you're right about the application should have picked the JSF libraries shipped with Jboss however I'm just unable to figure out the issue with that.

Comment: Are those libraries exposed to the application? Can you find it? Where are those jars located

Comment: Yes I believe they are as I found those libraries in the folder hierarchy I mentioned in the updated post.

Comment: https://community.jboss.org/wiki/RemoveJSF refer to this. For understanding purpose.